# xDoclet, Maven and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven-2

I am having some trouble setting up xDocklet and getting this error.

> Error resolving version for plugin 'xdoclet:maven2-xdoclet2-plugin' from the repositories

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>codehaus-plugins</id>
      <url>http://dist.codehaus.org/</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

     <plugin>
      <groupId>xdoclet</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven2-xdoclet2-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>xdoclet</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <goals>
             <goal>xdoclet</goal>
             </goals>
             </execution>
             </executions>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                   <groupId>xdoclet-plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>xdoclet-plugin-qtags</artifactId>
                   <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                    <groupId>xdoclet-plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xdoclet-taglib-qtags</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>xdoclet</goal>
                    </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <configs>
                        <config>
                        <components>
                          <component>                                          <classname>org.xdoclet.plugin.qtags.impl.QTagImplPlugin</classname>
                           </component>
                           <component>
                                            <classname>org.xdoclet.plugin.qtags.impl.QTagLibraryPlugin</classname>
<params>                                             <packagereplace>org.xdoclet.plugin.${xdoclet.plugin.namespace}.qtags</packagereplace>
</params>
</component>
<component>
<classname>org.xdoclet.plugin.qtags.doclipse.QTagDoclipsePlugin</classname>
<params>
<filereplace>qtags.xml</filereplace>
<namespace>${xdoclet.plugin.namespace}</namespace>
</params>
</component>
<component>
<classname>org.xdoclet.plugin.qtags.confluence.QTagConfluencePlugin</classname>
<params>
<destdir>${project.build.directory}/tag-doc</destdir>
<namespace>${xdoclet.plugin.namespace}</namespace>                                               <filereplace>${xdoclet.plugin.namespace}.confluence</filereplace>
</params>
</component>
</components>
<includes>**/*.java</includes>
<params>
<destdir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xdoclet</destdir>
</params>
</config>
</configs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Some of my questions.

- Would you recommend me with going
  with xDocklet. Is there any
  alternative for it?
- Is it one of the best way, as hbm's
  does get generated automatically.
- Any suggestions on the way how my
  Java Objects should get persisted in
  the DB?
- Any good tutorials over xDocklet
  Maven and Hibernate.

**I am using xDocklet to generate HBM's automatically by annotating my POJO's.**

Comment: Why not use JPA annotations, rather than xdoclets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are annotating your POJO's, you should definitely use Hibernate Annotations (or better: JPA). xDoclet was a good solution when Annotations were not available in Java.